# Why does server throw Q Code 19 only when both CPUs installed?

Tags: memory, hardware, boot, central-processing-unit, asus

I've got two identical intel CPUs in an Asus board with one stick of ram each. On power up, board immediately throws code 19 ("SB initialize before installed memory"). I've tested each CPU individually, as well as each stick of ram. When using a single cpu, the system boots fine with either one or two sticks of ram installed. The only time I have issues is when I install the second CPU. Am I missing something critical to dual-CPU builds that isn't done in single-CPU builds?

MB: ASUS Z10PE-D16

CPU: 2x Intel E5-1620V4 3.5Ghz, socket LGA2011V4, 140w

RAM: 2x Supermicro (sticker says Samsung) M393A4K40CB1-CRC4Q 32GB ECC DDR4 2400

PSU: FSP Twins Pro 700W

Comment: Did you forget to update the BIOS?

Comment: I updated it to the most recent version from the manufacturer website. I did notice there was also a package for updating the firmware, but I was a little hesitant to use it because nothing I've found so far suggested it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Received an answer from a user on another forum:

The 1620V4 only supports single CPU configurations: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/92991/intel-xeon-processor-e51620-v4-10m-cache-3-50-ghz/specifications.html

Comment: Wish I'd seen this yesterday sorry, would've been an easy one (https://www.asus.com/uk/Motherboards-Components/Motherboards/Workstation/Z10PED16_WS/HelpDesk_CPU/)